# How to change color of overflow menu group divider?

Tags: java, android

I've read every answer to this question that I can find, and the closest I've come to a solution is a style change (to "android:dropDownListViewStyle") that causes my altered divider (a drawable) to appear between every menu item, not just the groups.

Normally I wouldn't care about this, but Google's pre-launch report claims that the group divider has a low contrast compared to the background. The report refers to the layout item with id "group_divider". I can't find any reference to that id either.

Has anyone successfully changed the menu group divider, and if so, how?

The below images are the current unstyled menu, the menu after applying the style, and the menu the way I want it to look.

The style is done with this in the main app theme:

```
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.DropDownListView</item>
```

That referenced style is:

```
<style name="AppTheme.DropDownListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider_horizontal_bright_opaque</item>
</style>
```

[image: Current unstyled menu]

[image: After styling]

[image: Desired styling]

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use a custom style in the styles file to achieve this and assign the color and apply the style in the manifest.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my question, I tried that for this in my main app theme:

<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.DropDownListView</item>

That worked, but put a divider between every item, not just the groups.

Comment: maybe post a screenshot to show the look that you would like and the result you got?

Comment: OK, done - added to the original question. The style adds the styled divider between every menu item rather than between the item groups.